# How to show both text and image from the web in jlabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to display both image from the web and text in `JLabel` only the image will show.

```
jlabel.setText("Hello" + "http://");
```

Comment: I want to code it this way, is it possible.               jlabel.settext("<html>" + "text here" + "<img src='http://www.url.com/image.jpg'></html>") 
it will only display the image.

Comment: that should work, and display both the text and the image

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.url.com/image.jpg");
Image image = ImageIO.read(url);
jlabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
jlabel.setText("the text");
```

Comment: While preferred, beware, ImageIO is a blocking call, meaning it will block the current thread until it has loaded the image +1

Answer (score 0):

JLabel has a [`setIcon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) method which you can use to set the image, pass it an [`ImageIcon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html), which can be created from an [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html):

```
jlabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL("http:/...")));
jlabel.setText("Hello");
```

You can also include an image through [HTML directly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html):

```
jlabel.setText("<html><img src=\"http://...\"></html>");
```